# Could not find play-services v 7.8.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to compile my app with new google play servises (7.8.0), I add dependency to gradle.build file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

but I get strange compilation error:

```
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.jar
...
```

I use the latest version of Android build tools - 23.0.1

**UPD:** there is no gms folder in jcenter repository

[image]

Comment: Have you also updated the **Android Support Repository** and **Google Play services** to the latest versions (in the Android SDK Manager)?

Comment: yes, Android Support Repository version is 19 and Google Play services - 26

Comment: I'm pretty sure `play-services` is supposed to come from the local maven repo that's part of the Android SDK. Can you check whether `<path_to_android_sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services` has a folder for the version of the module you're attempting to reference (`7.8.0` that is)?

Comment: there is no such path in my android sdk, only <path_to_android_sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The **Android Support Repository** that you install from the Android SDK Manager should be the `m2repository`: http://i.imgur.com/KqFZAO8.png. Any chance you have more than one Android SDK installation on your machine?

Comment: Thanks MH., I just downloaded Google Repository, not only Google Support Repository

Comment: And of course I overlooked the **Google Repository** (which installs the Google libraries into that same `m2repository`). Glad to hear you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because jcenter is not added to the list of repositories. In your gradle..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
.
.
.
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: there is jcenter repository

Comment: Do you also have jcenter() in repositories outside buildscript?